# Is it possible to access Silverlight application isolated storage from a desktop application?

Tags: c#, silverlight, isolatedstorage

I have a Silverlight application that creates log files in its Isolated Storage and I want to create a client tool (a seperate desktop application, i.e WinForm, WPF) that can collect the log files from the Isolated Storage.

From my understanding, the isolated storage path is locate in folders path as [this site](http://kalpesh2804.blogspot.ca/2011/06/silverlight-isolated-storage-folder-out.html) said and their folder name and path for the application is pretty random.

So I want to use [IsolatedStorageScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc9b5sy.aspx) method to access my Silverlight application Isolated Storage.  But I believe I will need the parameter **assemblyIdentity** so it get the access.

In the msdn, the parameter only describe as:

```
assemblyIdentityType: System.Object
An object that contains evidence for the code assembly identity.
```

So what should I pass in order to access another application isolated storage?  Or am I going to wrong direction and it is not possible?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair That's just access to its own application Isolated Storage...is not toward another application isolated storage....